# Syntax Error declaring variables in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a problem with the following query:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO posts
(
-- not relevant
)
VALUES
(
-- insert works as intended
);
COMMIT WORK AND CHAIN;

DECLARE @insertId INT; -- this is where i get the syntax error
SET @insertId = LAST_INSERT_ID();

UPDATE posts
SET guid = CONCAT('foo.bar?p=', @insertId)
WHERE id = @insertId;

-- continue to work with the variable
INSERT INTO postmeta(post_id, key, value)
VALUES
(@insertId, ..., ...),
(@insertId, ..., ...),
(@insertId, ..., ...),
(@insertId, ..., ...);
COMMIT WORK;
```

Basically I insert a row, and need to update it, using the auto incremented id **immediately** after the insert (to make sure I get the correct value out of the function LAST_INSERT_ID).
Then I need to fill an other table, also using the auto incremented id. In this use case I figured, that I need to store the value in a variable.
Why do i get the following error message?
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE @insertId INT; SET @insertId = LAST_INSERT_ID();' at line 1"
Is the problem that I don't create a procedure or user defined function?

Comment: There's no reason to change the delimiter to enter this sequence of statements, but if you do change it, you need to terminate all statements with the new delimiter.

Comment: @Nick You are right, I removed the delimiter changes. I still get the same error unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a quick search and found this on the MariaDB website (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/user-defined-variables/):

"Since user-defined variables type cannot be declared, the only way to force their type is using CAST() or CONVERT()"

I think the solution is just removing the declare statement since there are examples on their site making variables without declaring them.

I hope this works, I'm not really familiar with MariaDB!

Comment: Thanks, removing the DECLARE statement worked perfectly!